# Plot a Tile map with the ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to create a tile map with Kibana. My conf file logstash works correctly and generates all what Kibana needs to plot a tile map. This is my conf logstash :

```
input {
    file {
            path => "/home/ec2-user/part.csv"
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {

    csv {
            separator => ","
            columns => ["kilo_bytes_total","ip","session_number","request_number_total","duration_minutes_total","referer_list","filter_match_count_avg","request_number_avg","duration_minutes_avg","kilo_bytes_avg","segment_duration_avg","req_by_minute_avg","segment_mix_rank_avg","offset_avg_avg","offset_std_avg","extrem_interval_count_avg","pf0_avg","pf1_avg","pf2_avg","pf3_avg","pf4_avg","code_0_avg","code_1_avg","code_2_avg","code_3_avg","code_4_avg","code_5_avg","volume_classification_filter_avg","code_classification_filter_avg","profiles_classification_filter_avg","strange_classification_filter_avg"]

    }



    geoip {

        source => "ip"
        database => "/home/ec2-user/logstash-5.2.0/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"
        target => "geoip"
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
        add_tag => "geoip"

    }


    mutate {

    convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]

    }
}

output {

    elasticsearch {

    index => "geotrafficip"
    }
}
```

And this is what that generates :

[image]

It looks cool. Trying to create my tile map, I have this message :

[image]

What to do ?

It seems that I must add somewhere the possiblity to use dynamic templates.. Should I create a template and add it to my file conf logstash ?

Can anybody give me some feedback ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the Kibana settings for your index, you'll need at least one field to show up with a type of `geo_point` to be able to get anything on a map.

If you don't already have a `geo_point` field, you'll need to re-index your data after setting up an appropriate mapping for the `geoip.coordinates` field.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42004303/2785358

If you are using a relatively new version of Elasticsearch (2.3 or later), it's relatively easy to re-index your data.  You need to create a new index with the correct mapping, use the re-index API to copy the data to the new index, delete the original index and then re-index back to the original name.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `geoip` filter wrong and are trying to convert the longitude and latitude to float. Get rid of your `mutate` filter and change the `geoip` filter to this.

```
geoip {
    source => "ip"
    fields => ["latitude","longitude"]
    add_tag => "geoip"
}
```

This will create the appropriate fields. And the required GeoJSON object.